# The StackExchange website keeps me logged in between sessions without asking me

Tags: bug, security, website

The login screen for StackExchange/AskUbuntu has no option to select or deselect a "keep me logged in" function, but it retains the login by default.

Retaining an everlasting login session without the user's permission has got to be some kind of bug or design flaw.

The security implications are obviously less than for a website with financial and/or personal details, but they are still there, and should be locked down.

Comment: It's not everlasting. Your login cookie will expire.  If you want to logout, click the logout button.

Comment: The "Keep me logged in" checkboxes have never worked for me, on any computer, OS or browser. If you don't want to stay logged in, just log out, or do what Fabby suggested.

Answer (score 1):

That's what browser settings are for: if you insist on being logged out, set the StackExchange/AskUbuntu cookie to "Allow for session" in the exception rules.

*Applause*